# while doing subset sum whose sum equals to B i am not able to get correct result

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

the code is very simple i am taking or not taking an element from A array and using left i am keeping track left sum it is *interview bit* problem

**Subset Sum Problem!**

```
class Solution:

    def solve(self, A, B):
            
        dp = []
        for _ in range(len(A)+1):
            dp.append([-1]*(B+1))
            
        def rec(index,left):
            
            if left < 0 or index==len(A):
                return False
            elif left == 0:
                return True
                
            if dp[index][left] != -1:
                return dp[index][left]
            
            

            dp[index][left] = rec(index+1,left) or rec(index+1,left-A[index])
            return dp[index][left]
            
            
        if rec(0,B):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

why this code is giving wrong output
if i am getting left < 0 and index == n then i am returning False
but this below one is correct

```
class Solution:

    def solve(self, A, B):
        
        dp = [[-1 for _ in range(B+1)] for _ in range(len(A)+1)]
        
        def rec(index, left):
            if index == len(A):
                if left == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False

            if dp[index][left] != -1:
                return dp[index][left]

            # Excluding the current element
            exclude = rec(index + 1, left)
            
            # Including the current element
            include = False
            if left - A[index] >= 0:
                include = rec(index + 1, left - A[index])
            
            dp[index][left] = exclude or include
            return dp[index][left]

        return int(rec(0, B))
```

Comment: Can there be negative numbers in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that your `rec` function returns `False` when `index==len(A)`. However, it doesn't then take into account that `left` might be 0, which would still indicate success.

So swap the order of the tests, first testing whether `left == 0`:

```
        if left == 0:
            return True
        elif left < 0 or index==len(A):
            return False
```

It was not mentioned in the question, but apparently it is assumed that the input values are non-negative, as the code that you call correct does not work well for inputs with negative values, like for instance `solve([-4, 14], 10)` produces an error with that code.

With that assumption in mind you did well to bail out immediately with `left < 0`, which the other code version doesn't do, losing time with further recursive calls that lead to nothing.